# spring-ws -- how to create java-interface from WSDL?

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

I'm creating a WSDL-first webservice with spring-ws in gradle.

Some examples I have been looking at
  (e g https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/ )
it seems they will **only** generate the java-classes from the XSD-schema,
but **no** java-interface (or abstract-class) from the WSDL service-operations?

Also, in the spring-ws doc, it says "... in Spring-WS, writing the WSDL by hand is not required ...".

- Is it correctly understood that spring-ws will **not** generate any java-interface or class for the actual service itself?
- Is it possible to **override** this default behaviour and **force** it to do so?

I would like to ensure the full WSDL is correctly and completely implemented...

Comment: The point of spring-ws is you don't need to write a WSDL in the first place: if you need to define an operation, you can just write a method for it (e.g. `CountryEndpoint.getCountry()`). Then Spring will generate a WSDL at run time based on your annotated POJOs.

Comment: See my comment to malaguna below -- it's not really "contract first" then -- rather a mix between contract-first and code-first, isn't it?

Comment: There certainly are use-cases when you WANT to go WSDL-first.
Currently, we are migrating from a legacy SOAP-implementation to spring-boot and now decided on CXF instead to ensure we generate a compatible java-api from the old WSDL. In an earlier project, we were provided a fixed WSDL from a partner-company, and asked to implement it -- for them to integrate with our system.

Comment: this can be nicely done in Maven with `jaxws-maven-plugin`. Maybe you want to search how to do that in Gradle (Sorry, not familiar with Gradle..)

Answer (score 1):

With spring-ws you can build contract first WS, although it is not necessary to build your WSDL, because it can generate it dynamically.

For java objects, spring-ws allows you to marshall/unmarshall using jaxb2 or similar. This way, you can obtain java classes from XSD, but this code generation is made by the marshaller.

From a server point of view, you create WS Endpoints that match WSDL operations. That Endpoints are annotated and bound to a request/response java objects. Thus, spring can generate dynamically WSDL, but you can use your own WSDL.

From a client point of view, you need a `WSTemplate` that needs to retrieve a WSDL (static or dynamic, it doesn't mind). Using this way, `WSTemplate` ensure you can call all server endpoints, without implementing client stubs or generated code.

I rather prefer to use static WSDL, because dynamic generation can't ensure that your WSDL change if you upgrade Spring or so, and this could break compatibility with your clients.

However, while I am developing I use dynamic WSDL, for the shake of simplicity. Once I have the service I want, I get dynamically generated WSDL (customize if I need) and use it as static. That WSDL is full for all the endpoints.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well contract-first is a formal definition, see [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/why-contract-first.html), and Spring can be used as a contract-first way to implement WS, see [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html). I only tell you, that it is possible to use spring-ws wsdl dynamic feature, to prototype. It is your choice to use it as you want.

Comment: yes, I know you can just publish the predefined WSDL rather than the dynamically generated one.
But AFAIU, then you have no compile-time checks that the java-code will actually work for the WSDL.
So it's just as much "code-first" as it is "contract-first"...

Comment: Compare how it's done in CXF, where the tool will generate java-interface with correct annotations and correct method-signatures from the WSDL.
That's what "contract-first" means to me.
That was my original question, if it was somehow POSSIBLE to achieve the same in spring-ws.
But now I think not.....

Comment: I don't think so. Contract-first is not auto-generate code first. You can be contract-first without generating code. Two parts can define a contract (the WSDL) and each one can use different technologies as CXF and SpringWS and work together with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only interfaces from WSDL just use wsimport command. Its part of jdk so no extra things needed.

run the commend: wsimport -keep wsdlUrl
it will generate all the interfaces and client code (.java as well as .class)to hit the web service. just search your interface.

Let your generated URL is :http://www.host.com/testservice?WSDL

then commend will be wsimport -keep http://www.host.com/testservice?WSDL
there are much more options with wsimport commend use as you want. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

Answer (score 0):

ws import generate all the client side code.
asn wellm  as much more things try wsimport, wsgen for more details